# VBA: After assigning an initialized and populated Array to a Variable, an uninitialized Array is stored instead

Tags: arrays, vba, variables

I have a simple function `KeepItArray()` to handle data from [`Range.Value2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value2)

```vb
Private Function KeepItArray(ByVal Value As Variant) As Variant()
    Dim tempArray() As Variant
    If IsArray(Value) Then
        tempArray = Value 'Passed value is an array, no changes needed
    Else
        ReDim tempArr(1 To 1, 1 To 1) As Variant
        tempArr(1, 1) = Value 'Not an array, return it as item(1,1) in 2D array
    End If
    KeepItArray = tempArray
End Function
```

This works perfectly in a simple example:

```vb
Public Sub test()
    Dim s As Variant
    Set s = Selection
    
    Dim v As Variant
    v = KeepItArray(s.Value2)
    
    Debug.Print v(1, 1)
End Sub
```

**BUT** When I use it in my code, it returns like "uninitialized array" when non-array value is passed.

Just see these screenshots:
`Range.Value2` is passed to `KeepItArray` function, because `Area` is one-cell range, `Range.Value2` property doesn't return array, but directly the value.
[image: Range.Value2 is passed to KeepItArray function]

`tempArr` is sucesfully created and `Value` is placed as `item(1,1)`
[image: tempArr is sucesfully created and Value is placed as item(1,1)]

But I don't get what happened now - `tempArr` value is not assigned to `KeepItArray` variable!
[image: tempArr value is not assigned to KeepItArray variable]

If code continue, you can see that same  value is assigned to the variable `AreaValues(Index)`.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ReDim a new variable called `tempArr`

You return the earlier variable `tempArray`

You have a typo.

Comment: Highly recommend @Lluser to insert `Option Explicit` at the top of the module to help pick up undeclared variable like `tempArr` (and thus realised there's a typo)

Comment: @RaymondWu, I thought of that too, but I believe that `ReDim` also defines a variable so it wouldn't work here.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Oh, this is embarrasing. I waited till next day to see it with a clear mind, but still haven't seen it. You are right, `RedDim` initializes the `tempArr` variable, and the Intellisense suggests it above the right `tempArray`.